# Error in reading a file in java

Tags: java, readfile, nosuchelementexception

I've been trying to practice I/O file programming and I'm still at the basics. Writing into a file using the java was simple enough but reading to a file is beginning to give me a headache. Here's a simple program I tried to run(btw, I based the program from a book by Liang) .

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class Reading {
private static Scanner n;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    File files = new File("samples.txt");
    n = new Scanner(files);

    while(n.hasNext())
    {
        String firstName = n.next();
        String mi = n.next();
        String lastName = n.next();
        int score = n.nextInt();
        System.out.println(
        firstName + " " + mi + " " + lastName + " " + score);
    }

    n.close();
}

}
```

Here's the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at OOPFinals.Reading.main(Reading.java:17)
```

How do I make this program work?
Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working given that the right input file "*samples.txt*" is provided. For example, given the following input:

```
Richard Phillips Feynman 100
Paul Adrien Dirac 90
```

Everything works fine, however if you use the following:

```
Richard Feynman 100
Paul Adrien Dirac 90
```

then you obtain the **NoSuchElementException**. In the last example, I removed the middle name that your program is expecting. As such, we can conclude that you are expecting to read information in a file with no information left to read. I recommend something like the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.File;
public class Reading {
private static Scanner n;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    File files = new File("samples.txt");
    n = new Scanner(files);
    String data;
    while(n.hasNextLine() && !(data = n.nextLine()).equals(""))
    {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data);

        if(st.countTokens() >= 4) {
            String firstName = (String) st.nextElement();        
            String mi = (String) st.nextElement();
            String lastName = (String) st.nextElement();
            int score = Integer.parseInt( (String) st.nextElement());
            System.out.println(
            firstName + " " + mi + " " + lastName + " " + score);

        } else {
            System.err.println("This line is malformed!");
        }
    }

    n.close();
}

}
```

In this program, you can have a sample file that has empty lines and it expects to read 4 tokens per line or else it prints an error message informing you that a line has malformed input.

Answer (score 2):

The `NoSuchElementException` is thrown by `Scanner.next()` and means there are no more tokens to be found in the file.

The problem here is that your `while()` loop only guarantees that there is at least ONE token left to read from the file, however on each iteration of the loop you are reading in FIVE tokens.

Comment: I's sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the term' token'. I'd appreciate it if you could explain a bit simplier

Comment: A token is the next piece of information you try to read from the Scanner. I'd recommend reading its documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: @A.Gritz Basically, each time you use a `Scanner.next` method, you're fetching the next token acquired or acquirable by the `Scanner`, while the `.hasNext` method only checks for the existence of *one* (the next) token.

Comment: @AlmightyR thank you! I didn't really know what .hasNext function was

Answer (score 2):

What is happening in your code, you are trying to read from the Scanner although there's nothing left there to read.
What you should do - You need to check n.hasNext() before each call to n.next() or n.nextInt(), or just read the entire line (which seems exactly what you want):

```
while (n.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = n.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: How do i check n.hasNext()? I'm sorry if i need to be this specific>.<

Comment: If you assume you have 4 tokens in the list, before each one check n.hasNext() or n.hasNextInt() etc. Why don't you use a FileReader and just read lines? Check out this examlple for reading a file - https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Comment: @A.Gritz - I edited the code and added a sample for you to see.

Comment: I've seen your program. Although I understood most of it, I'm not too sure what BufferedReader does. is there any source you could recommend that i read about it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you're reading a file you'll run into various characters. Some are letters, some are numbers, and some are **integers**. You need to check whether it's a letter, number, or an **integer** because the following line assumes you are passing an integer:

```
    int score = n.nextInt();
```

It can be resolved by checking for **integers**:

```
    int score = 0;
    if(n.hasNextInt()) { score = n.nextInt(); }
```

When you're reading from the program, make sure to take Cathial's answer into consideration. By using `hasNext()`, you're only checking if there is one string, also known as a token. You should check if there are `n` strings available where `n` is the number of `.next()` functions in your loop.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the program terminated without a reason.

Comment: @A.Gritz If my answer solves your exercise, make sure to click the checkmark.